# Replace line breaks in plain text with BR tag in Django views

Tags: python, django, formatting, newline

Django provides [linebreaks template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-linebreaks) which works similarly to a PHP function `nl2br`.

It works well, however it processes the given text with every request, what is a waste of resources. I would rather do it once, before saving it to a database.

Is there any equivalent function to use in a Django view?

Comment: I would suggest not doing this. What if you ever want to display that text as plain text rather than HTML? On the other side, replacing `\n` with `<br>` is a linear time operation, so it's mostly as efficient as just reading the text and displaying it. You shouldn't be concerned of such overhead, as it might save you 1-2% of rendering time (unless you have done profiling and have something to prove me wrong).

Comment: It's an unnecessary waste. Small, but performed with every request. I probably won't need to change it back, but if I ever do, it'll not be a big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you are storing it in a database... then the resulting extra query is going to add WAY more overhead to your request response cycle than you would be saving by caching the output of some rather efficient Python text transformation.

A better solution would be *caching* the view. Django has lots of support for very [flexible caching arrangements](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

Don't be the [premature optimization guy or gal](http://sam-koblenski.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/beware-premature-optimzation-can-happen.html). Especially such tiny optimizations. Most of your request response cycle is spent waiting for the database or in network latency.

Answer (score 9):

The linebreaks template tag is just a wrapper around the line breaks function from `django.utils.html`, so you can just use that directly.